# Kickstand compatible with 2011 TREK Utopia

Tags: accessories, kickstand

Will a kickstand fit on a [2011 Trek Utopia](http://www.trekbikes.com/us/en/bikes/2011/archive/utopia)? I'm told the standard that bolts in near the front gear won't fit and I read that the one that mounts near the rear axle won't work with disc brakes.

Comment: @jason - Have reworded your question a bit to remove chatty, forum-style language, but please revert my edit if I'm off-base.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to get a standard kickstand on there unless there is some proprietary frame weld-on by Trek where the stand usually goes. Get a Greenfield kickstand with a plate that looks like this: http://harriscyclery.net/images/library/catalogs/soc/p350X350m/KI1005.jpg

I'll bet this can be made to fit. However, truth be told, a kickstand doesn't really belong on a mountain bike unless it's a bike from a department store like walmart, etc.

Comment: Interesting question. Have asked a companion question that's more general, although it won't necessarily help with this bike: [Kickstands and mountain bikes](http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/q/7413/8).