# Why are kickstands so much hated by MTB bikers?

Tags: parts

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Kickstands and mountain bikes](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/7413/kickstands-and-mountain-bikes)

Is it just around my country, or is this a global thing?

Most bikers riding MTB specifically do not have kickstands. They simply drop a bike on the ground, or lean it somewhere, when they need to park it.

Why is that? Is the added weight really that much of a trouble?